# C# - LINQ First() and an implicit reference?

Tags: c#, linq

I have some code that at first glance makes no sense to me.

Question: Is there some kind of implicit reference happening here? It seems like only non-matched items are added and the first section of the 'if' is doing nothing. Am I correct in that? (I've added my comments (///) to what I understand to flush out my question). (//) comments are original code comments

```
 public static List<BAPresModel> MergeBudgetApprovalByProgramPMLists(
    List<BAPresModel> sourceList, List<BAPresModel> destList)
{
    /// we create this and use it but it seems to never impact destList that I can tell
    BAPresModel dstBA = new BAPresModel();

    // Merge sourceList into destList.
    foreach (BAPresModel sl in sourceList)
    {
        var qryDestList = from dl in destList
                          where sl.FiscalYearID == dl.FiscalYearID
                          where sl.X == dl.X
                          where sl.Y == dl.Y
                          select dl;
        if (qryDestList.Count() > 0)  // we found a match in the destination list.
        {
            /// I researched -First()- but don't see anything clarifying my question
            /// Is this creating a reference back to destList from dstBA somehow?
            dstBA = qryDestList.First();
            /// this applies the math (adding sl.X to dstBA.X )
            dstBA.X = Maths.AddNullableDecimals(dstBA.X, sl.X);
            dstBA.Y = Maths.AddNullableDecimals(dstBA.Y, sl.Y);
        }
        else  // no match, so add the sourceList item to the destination list.
        {
            destList.Add(sl);
        }
    }

    /// as far as I can tell the only thing this method actually does is return the original
    /// destList with 'sl' matched items added to it
    /// all of the work on dstBA is useless??
    return destList;
}
```

Thank you for your time and assessment

Comment: Is BAPresModel a struct/value type?

Comment: The line `BAPresModel dstBA = new BAPresModel();` is poorly written and placed. If you deleted it, and put in `var` in front of `dstBA = qryDestList.First()` that may clear it up a little? PS It would also be normal C# to use `&&` instead of multiple `where`.

Comment: What is this method supposed to be doing? It seems to have bugs, assuming `BAPresModel` is a class.

Comment: If `BAPresModel` is a class, your code first tries to figure out if it has an object in `destList` with the particular fiscal year, X and Y already, and if not it will add the first it found in `sourceList` with that information. The issue is that if it encounters that particular combination again, it will add X and Y from the new entry from `sourceList` to the previously seen entry in `destList`, thus screwing up that matching algorithm that looks for matches on fiscal year, **X and Y**.

Comment: To answer your questions: "/// Is this creating a reference back to destList from dstBA somehow?": **No**. It is grabbing the first value from the LINQ query that extracts values from `sourceList`. If those values are instances of a class, then the next part of the code adjusting X and Y properties will adjust the X and Y properties of that class instance. If it is a struct, then you're right, adjusting X and Y is pointless. Please clarify whether `BAPresModel` is a class or a struct.

Comment: It seems this code is supposed to grab objects from sourceList and add them to destList, except if it has already an existing object in destList with the same fiscal year, X and Y, then modify it instead, accumulating the values of the new object it found in sourceList. The issue with this is that by modifying X and Y, you're screwing over this matching part. Example, you have fiscal year, X and Y as (2022, 10, 10) and then another (2022, 10, 10) and a third (2022, 10, 10). You add the first, as it wasn't found, then you modify it to (2022, 20, 20) from the second, and then third isn't found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming BPAPresModel is a class

```
      dstBA = qryDestList.First();
```

effectively gets a pointer to the first matching entry returned by that query.

```
        /// this applies the math (adding sl.X to dstBA.X )
        dstBA.X = Maths.AddNullableDecimals(dstBA.X, sl.X);
        dstBA.Y = Maths.AddNullableDecimals(dstBA.Y, sl.Y);
```

so those 2 lines are changing it in the original destList

Class types in c# are called 'reference' types. Because  in things like

```
   BAPresModel foo = SomeFunction();
```

foo is a reference to the actual object on the heap. If you are a c or c++ dev think

```
   BAPresModel *foo = SomeFunction();
```

so not an 'implicit' reference, an 'actual' reference